# Is it possible to use a super class in this exemple, common to all the classes I created?

Tags: python, superclass

I have all these classes that are quite similar, except their covar_module. I was wondering if I could create a common super class, that has all the attributes and functions and the subclasses only have the covar_module. I am quite new to python, so I don't know how the synthax would be.

```
class RbfGP(ExactGP, GPyTorchModel):
    _num_outputs = 1  # to inform GPyTorchModel API

    def __init__(self, train_X, train_Y):
        # squeeze output dim before passing train_Y to ExactGP
        super().__init__(train_X, train_Y.squeeze(-1), GaussianLikelihood())
        self.mean_module = ConstantMean()
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.ScaleKernel(
            base_kernel= gpytorch.kernels.RBFKernel(ard_num_dims=train_X.shape[-1]),
        )
        self.to(train_X)  # make sure we're on the right device/dtype

    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        return MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)


class Matern12GP(ExactGP, GPyTorchModel):
    _num_outputs = 1  # to inform GPyTorchModel API

    def __init__(self, train_X, train_Y):
        # squeeze output dim before passing train_Y to ExactGP
        super().__init__(train_X, train_Y.squeeze(-1), GaussianLikelihood())
        self.mean_module = ConstantMean()
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.ScaleKernel(
            base_kernel=gpytorch.kernels.MaternKernel(nu=0.5, ard_num_dims=train_X.shape[-1]),
        )
        self.to(train_X)  # make sure we're on the right device/dtype

    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        return MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)


class Matern32GP(ExactGP, GPyTorchModel):
    _num_outputs = 1  # to inform GPyTorchModel API

    def __init__(self, train_X, train_Y):
        # squeeze output dim before passing train_Y to ExactGP
        super().__init__(train_X, train_Y.squeeze(-1), GaussianLikelihood())
        self.mean_module = ConstantMean()
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.ScaleKernel(
            base_kernel=gpytorch.kernels.MaternKernel(nu=1.5, ard_num_dims=train_X.shape[-1]),
        )
        self.to(train_X)  # make sure we're on the right device/dtype

    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        return MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not something like this:

```
class GP(ExactGP, GPyTorchModel):
    _num_outputs = 1  # to inform GPyTorchModel API

    def __init__(self, train_X, train_Y, base_kernel, **kwargs):
        # squeeze output dim before passing train_Y to ExactGP
        super().__init__(train_X, train_Y.squeeze(-1), GaussianLikelihood())
        self.mean_module = ConstantMean()
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.ScaleKernel(
            base_kernel=base_kernel(ard_num_dims=train_X.shape[-1], **kwargs),
        )
        self.to(train_X)  # make sure we're on the right device/dtype

    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        return MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)
```

then

```
rbf_gp = GP(train_x, train_y, base_kernel=gpytorch.kernels.RBFKernel)

matern_12_gp = GP(train_x, train_y, base_kernel=gpytorch.kernels.MaternKernel, nu=0.5)
```